# Slideshow goes crazy after navigating away and back to the page, Aurelia framework, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, aurelia

If I reload the page it fixes it. I tried to force a reload when navigating to the page, but was unsuccessful. Does anyone have any suggestions?

here is the page https://web-jam-back-dev.herokuapp.com/music
to cause the issue click back, then click /library in the menu (there is another slideshow on that page), then click back and click /ohaf (there is another slideshow on that page, so that's three total), now click back and click /music from the menu, and this slideshow will go crazy.

here is the link to the code
https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/music.js
https://github.com/WebJamApps/combined-front/blob/dev/src/music.html

Thank you in advance,
Josh Sherman

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that I needed to provide a unique ID for each slideshow so that the Jquery wasn't invoking it three times. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinitialize slider on route change success